# Connect to containers without specifying port in url (nginx)

Tags: port-forwarding, port, nginx, container, multi-account-containers

I want to connect to containers via nginx location blocks without making the port visible in the url for a large scale application
my current block is:

```
location ~"/name/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9])/"{
            set port $3;
            proxy_pass http://128.0.0.7:$port;
            proxy_header Host $host;
}
```

I want to access the url `/name/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9])/` with this `(.*)` unique id instead of `([0-9])` port

Comment: If you want to map arbitrary labels to port numbers, use a `map` block. See the [`map` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

Comment: Can I connect to docker containers with my website url using this without mentioning port in the url?